# CORS issue with Laravel 5 api and ionic 1 (Angular 1)

Tags: angularjs, api, ionic-framework, cors

Front-end application in Angular 1 and My APIs are built on Laravel and located in different server then sure i will face Cross Origin Request Sharing (CORS) problem and my APIs will not return expected results.

I faced the issue and according to some solutions I added some (following code)headers on index.php of Laravel but still I was not able to solve the issue.

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');

**ERROR Message:** on chrome browser,

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 2):

You should not modify your headers manually at index.php. It is possible that Laravel overrides headers, moreover you cannot determine when your `header()` function will be called (if even).

You could implement some kind of interceptor that captures every request and sets CORS headers. Or you can try some library like https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: Thanks @Łukasz Szcześniak for your respond, really appreciate, now its working...

Answer (score 0):

Are your headers only being added to a GET/POST? Because the problem is in the preflight OPTIONS request - you need to ensure that **at a minimum**, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header is returned for OPTIONS requests.